# How to correctly make enemies spawn and enter from off-screen?

Tags: c++, sfml, game-development

In a 2D game of survival shooter, I am trying to get my enemies to spawn and enter from off-screen but I am not able to make it work quite right. I have tried for many hours and I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I am randomly spawning enemies so sometimes they spawn off-screen but sometimes they spawn on-screen.

Edit: Note that the origin is (0, 0) which would be the centre of the screen. So if I did `enemy->mPosition = Float2(0.0f, 0.0f);`, enemies would spawn in the centre of the screen.

Here is a code snippet:

```
// Random value between 0.0f and 1.0f
float FRand()
{
    return ((float)std::rand() / (float)RAND_MAX);
}

enemy->mPosition = Float2(0.0f, 0.0f);

//screenSize = {1280, 720}
Float2 screenSize = (Float2)renderTex->getSize();     
 
//screenSizeHalf = {640, 360}                     
Float2 screenSizeHalf = screenSize/2.0f;    
                         
// Enemies sometimes spawn off-screen and sometimes on-screen instead of only off-screen.                 
enemy->mPosition = Float2(FRand() * screenSize.x - screenSizeHalf.x, FRand() * screenSize.y - screenSizeHalf.y);
```

Where is it going wrong?

Comment: You could do a little debugging and print out the values to see what they are.  You're already working at a disadvantage by using random numbers, thus the program changes each time.  So you might as well see what those values are, and pinpoint which ones cause the issue.  Second, all we have is your calculation -- we have no idea how, when or where this drawing takes place.

Comment: Well I thought the calculation is what is wrong which is why I ask. Sometimes the enemy gets spawned at (-249, -1) or (118, 74) for example which is inside the screen.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, the idea for the calculation is fine, but the random aspect to it seems wrong. If FRand does return only values between 0.0f and 1.0f the calculations can only return values inside the screen.
Best solutions would be to either change the calculation/random numbers or do a FloatRect of the screen/view and redo a random calculations if a spawn would happend inside it.

Comment: should have some format